# Did Zack have any lines in Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children?

Tags: final-fantasy-vii-advent-children

At the end of *Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children* when Cloud is in the healing water in the church with the kids getting their Geostigma cured, he sees Aerith and as she was away we see that Zack is leaning against the doorway (can be seen in [this video on Aerith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHTMn-0XYfI&t=19m38s)).

When i first saw the film i don't recall Zack having any lines but there is *Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children Complete* with extra scenes which i have yet to see yet (i've been told that Reno mentions meeting up with the other Turks like Cissnei)

So maybe i missed it in the original movie or maybe there's something only in the Complete version, but does Zack have any lines or even do anything at all besides show up at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering Zack has his voice actor listed in the original *Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children*'s credit... **yes, he spoke 2 lines near the ending.**

This happens after Cloud's final fight

> when Cloud is unconscious after the Remnants of Sephiroth's suicide attack. After a while, Aerith *and Zack* have a very short dialogue, rejecting Cloud's fate from "joining" them.
>   
>   
>   YouTube video: [Japanese voice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVMwPXzgjzE), [English dub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3PbcS5Gadk).

---

With the additional screen time for Zack in *Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children Complete*, he also has more lines compared to the original movie.

Comment: I'd like to point out that Zack is never *shown* speaking in the original version of the movie (which is probably why the OP missed it). His two lines are just general dialogue, and then it pans over to Zack and [spoiler] at the end of the scene